# Anyway to use HTTP Authentication with Axel Downloader?

Tags: download, http

Is there anyway to use http authentication with axel downloader?

I don't want to use another solution such as aria2c because they don't support more than 16 concurrent connections.

Answer (score 9):

You can set it in header by using -H option.

Example:

```
axel -a -n 4 -H 'Authorization: Basic [hashstring]' URL
```

Where `[hashstring]` is base64 encoded string from string "username:password".

Comment: I tried this to download using a https server, but I got `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized` as the output. What do I change in the command to get it to work?

Comment: Suggest to figure out the authentication API first. Might be documented depending on the server/service in question. Can also use web developer tools on your browser to see what are the issued requests when you access the resource manually. This is independent of axel, suggest to try with a different tool e.g. curl or postman first. Only take into account that axel supports up to 9 http headers as of now.