# HTTPS Authentication with Axel Downloader

Tags: authentication, download, https, axel

Is there a way to use https authentication with Axel to download files?

I have gone through [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80999/anyway-to-use-http-authentication-with-axel-downloader/114050#114050) and tried what was written, but to no extent. I got 
 `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized` 
as the output for this input command:
`axel -n 60 -k -H "Authorisation: Basic [some hash string]" "https://xxx.rar"` 
for which the hash string was generated using : 
`echo -n "username:password" | openssl base64`

So ultimately, I want to know, what do I change in the input command to be able to download the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard url scheme is: proto://user:password@host:port/path

```
axel -n 60 -k "https://user:password@host/xxx.rar"
```

Comment: So I tried this and got this as the output,
`HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`
 for the input `axel -n 60 "https://user:password@host/xxx.rar`, but I am thinking, since the path has the hosting name as well, should I repeat it or should I just cancel that particular part?